# Unable to access properties of SamlAssertion class after adding it via reference in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

After I add the reference via VS2010, I could see the class(I can see the lock symbol on the classes present in it) but I wasn't able to access the properties of its method. Can anyone point me to a workaround? I adding the System.IdentityModel.dll into my project reference. I am breaking my head over this from a couple of hours.

Comment: Make sure you have not set the target framework to ".NET framework Client Profile", instead pick the full one

Comment: Hi, I changed it to "NET framework 4 Client Profile" but still I am unable to access them. Am  I missing anything? Thanks.

Comment: This is the setting you do **not** want to have, make sure you have it set to ".NET framework 4". Can you post some sample code that shows your problem?

Comment: namespace ProxyLayer
{
    public class SAML 
    {
        public static string name = "Clint";
        public static string AssertionID = "h95483AAB699193993CA04E34887B9D8";
        public static string Issuer = "my.issuer.com";
        public static string NameQualifier = "www.tibco.com";
        public static string AuthenticationMethod = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:password";
        public static string dnsaddress = "config2450vm0.na.tibco.com";
        public static string ipaddress = "10.107.173.230";
        SamlAssertion sa = new SamlAssertion();

Comment: I then try to do sa.<property> which I am unable to access.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the solution. thanks a lot for your help .